# placing pop up based on the mouse position(x,y)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

here i need  to get the  mouse position that is its x,y value   based on that i can  place my modal pop up in that postion.
my pop is  define din xaml page here i will be assigning only its position where i need to place my modal pop up.

Comment: http://blogs.windowsclient.net/silverlaw/archive/2010/04/15/how-to-determine-new-childwindow-position-at-runtime-silverlight-3.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/baimey/SilverlightChartsCoordinatesMousemove11242009141413PM/SilverlightChartsCoordinatesMousemove.aspx

Comment: Check the above links, they r related to the mouse position only.